# Scala JavaConverters doesn't seem to work with collections returned by static methods

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I'm using a Java library from inside Scala 2.11 code. This Java library has a static `load` method that returns a `Map<String,String>`. Example usage in Java:

```
Map<String,String> map = Environment.load("dev");
```

I'm trying to get it working in Scala like so:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val map : Map[String,String] = Environment.load("dev").asJava
```

And I'm getting a compiler error:

> "*Cannot resolve symbol asJava*"

Any ideas?

Comment: the result of `.asScala` on a map is not a `Map[String, String]` (immutable one), it's `scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]`

Comment: And of course you should be using `.asScala`, not `.asJava`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `asScala` instead of `asJava`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val map: Map[String, String] = Environment.load("dev").asScala.toMap
```

Comment: Oh nice, so when do you use `asScala` and when do you use `asJava`?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup: Use `.asScala` when you want to convert a Java collection to a Scala collection; use `asJava` when you want to convert a Scala collection to a Java collection. Read the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) for more details.